# How to fit UMAP object with an embedding_ property of shape (200,2)

Tags: python, machine-learning

I'm trying to take the first 200 rows of my dataframe and pass it through a UMAP fit method but I'm not able to get it to shape the way I want at (200,2). Should I add an embedding parameter?

This is the code I have so far:

```
def example():
    feature_names = ['beer_name','review_appearance', 'review_aroma', 'review_palate', 'review_taste', 'review_overall']
    new_df = df[feature_names]
    final_df = new_df.groupby(['beer_name']).mean()
    scaler = StandardScaler()
    scaler.fit(final_df)
    results = scaler.transform(final_df)

    X_normalized_200 = results[0:200,:]
    umap_obj = umap.UMAP(set_op_mix_ratio=0.15, random_state = 0).fit(final_df)
    output=umap_obj
    
    return output
```

Snapshot of my dataframe:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `transform` method after fitting UMAP in order to get the coordinates of each point in the embedding.

```py
def example():
    feature_names = [
        "beer_name",
        "review_appearance",
        "review_aroma",
        "review_pallete",
        "review_taste",
        "review_overall",
    ]
    new_df = df[feature_names]
    final_df = new_df.groupby(["beer_name"]).mean()
    scaler = StandardScaler()
    scaler.fit(final_df)
    results = scaler.transform(final_df)

    X_normalized_200 = results[0:200, :]
    umap_obj = umap.UMAP(set_op_mix_ratio=0.15, random_state=0).fit(final_df)
    output = umap_obj.transform(X_normalized_200)  # missing this line

    return output
```